# How can I count subsequently equal values in an int array

Tags: java

I would like to count subsequently equal values in an int array and return an array with the count and another array with the value order.

E.g. i would like to transform:

```
int arr = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0};
```

To:

```
int arr = {11,5,4,3,3,4,4}; // The count
int idx = {0,1,2,0,1,2,0}; // The order
```

Can you help me achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your progress and where you got stuck?

Comment: get the first element and increase your counter (starting by one), if the next is the same. Otherwise put the counter in your new arr and the value into the idx. repeat until end. assign your new arr to the original arr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
int[] arr = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0};
//First determine how many subsequently equal values there are
int countEquals = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != arr[i-1]) {
        countEquals++;
    }
}
//Then calculate the order and count
int[] count = new int[countEquals];
int[] order = new int[countEquals];
int index = 0;
Arrays.fill(count, 1);
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[i-1]) {
        count[index]++;
    } else {
        order[index] = arr[i-1];
        index++;
    }
}
```